# how to pass string from c++ to delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I am new in delphi

I have following exported function in delphi:

```
function MyFunction(var FirstParam: PChar; var Second: PChar ): Boolean; export; stdcall;
```

and c++ caller function is like this:

```
typedef bool(*MYFUNC) (char *, char*);
```

but i am getting following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76C1F117 (user32.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x66646664.
```

what should be the reason?, you reply will help me a lot.

many thanks.

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception? *How* do you use the Delphi function? And when and where do you call it? With what arguments? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Also run your program in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and locate it in *your* source. Edit your question to include the MCVE and pointing out where in it the crash happens, and the values of all involved variables.

Comment: Which code can you change? The Delphi or the C++ declaration?

Comment: m_hModule = LoadLibrary(L"MyDLL.DLL");
 m_lpTest = (MYFUNC)GetProcAddress(m_hModule, "MyFunction");

Comment: The use of var paeans is wrong. You must fix that.

Comment: Let me ask again: Can you modify the Delphi code? Can you modify the C++ code?

Comment: @Ramkrushna you should NOT add important details as hard to find comments - you should EDIT your question text instead and add details there. In particular, tell what code (C++ or Delphi) is DLL and what is EXE, what code you cn chnge and what code you can not. We can change both C++ and Delphi codes to make them match - but you should tell us what you need. And do it in the question itself, not in extra comments plz

Comment: typedef bool __stdcall(MYFUNC) (char, char*); this works for me thanks

Comment: Please read @Arioch'The's comment above. Furthermore, the function signature you just posted doesn't match the Delphi prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyFunction(var FirstParam: PChar; var Second: PChar ): Boolean; export; stdcall;
```

passes the pointer arguments by reference (because of the `var`),

```
typedef bool(*MYFUNC) (char *, char*);
```

passes them by value. You have to make the signatures match.

You also have to match the calling conventions - the Delphi function is explicitly marked `stdcall`, the C++ function probably is `cdecl` by default.

**Update:** If I understand your comment correctly you have to adapt the C++ code to the Delphi side. This might look like this:

```
typedef bool __stdcall(*MYFUNC) (char*&, char*&);
```

Comment: I am loading Delphi DLL explicitly m_hModule = LoadLibrary(L"MyDLL.DLL");
 m_lpTest = (MYFUNC)GetProcAddress(m_hModule, "MyFunction");

Comment: @Uli you also have to harden for Unicode/MBCS issue. Since in C++ he uses `char` instead of `TCHAR` macro or `WCHAR` type then the corresponding Delphi code should also use strictly defined `PAnsiChar` not ambiguous `PChar`

Comment: Note that `PChar` in Delphi 2007 and earlier translates to `char*`, but in Delphi 2009 and later it translates to `wchar_t*` instead. So not only do you need to match the calling convention and the reference semantics, but also the correct data type.

Comment: typedef bool __stdcall(*MYFUNC) (char*, char*);   this works for me thanks